# PHP cannot connect to MySQL on RDS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Recently few days I run into a weird problem of php not able to connect to mysql on RDS, while manual connections are fine.

So I have several php scripts sitting on our server which is hosted on EC2, and these scripts are called by the clients to communicate with a mysql server sitting on RDS. The scripts are setup so that if any connection error occurs, they would send email notification to me.

So for the recent few days I'm receiving thousands of error emails from my scripts, at the first few days the errors were simple saying the server host is not recognized, but I am sure the address is correct. And now the errors are almost all saying "Host XXX is blocked because of many connection errors, unblock with mysqladmin flush-hosts..." If I flush the hosts, the errors come back to me after a while.

What confuses me the most is that, I cannot reproduce the problem! I tried connecting to the RDS server from my EC2 server through command line and through test php scripts... They all work! If I manually invoke the scripts sending me error emails, they work too! Looking at the RDS monitor, all stat looks normal, CPU is bouncing around 50%, and plenty of hard drive space.

So I'm totally confused right now... Can anyone provide me some insight about how to solve this problem? I don't even know where to look at now...

Comment: Have you read documentation? Are you testing the connection with the same user/passwd credentials? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blocked-host.html

Comment: @Paul No I have not called Amazon yet, I posted on their forum but they are not really looking at it.

Comment: @GirishRao Thank you but I have already read that, if I flush the hosts then after a while the same error comes back to me. And the credentials are all correct, I was even manually invoking the php scripts that sent me those errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check your connection to the mysql server and check for errors. Until then you can cron a  "flush hosts" to temporary fix the issue. Be aware that this should be used only as a temporary fix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Paul, after so long the problem went away simply by scaling the RDS up. I think this is a bug of Amazon's side that's not really documented, and yet the cause is mysterious. Anyways I'll accept your answer as to close this question.